# Throttles, Quotas and Pricing of Azure IoT Hub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

After reading about the throttles and quotas of Azure IoT Hub, I am struggling to understand how an IoT Hub can support millions of devices (Microsoft's promise). Maybe you guys can help. These are my thoughts so far:

Quote from [Microsoft doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-devguide/#throttling)

**Device connections:**

> 120/sec/unit (for S2), 12/sec/unit (for S1).  Minimum of 100/sec. For
>   example, two S1 units is 2*12 = 24/sec, but you will have at least
>   100/sec across your units. With nine S1 units you have 108/sec (9*12)
>   across your units.

**12/sec/unit** - does it mean that if I only have one scaling unit I can have max. 12 simultaneous connections at the same time? 
Or does it mean that I can open max. 12 new connection per second?

**What does "Minimum of 100/sec" mean?**

IoT Hub supports AMQP 1.0.
My understanding was that with this protocol I can have a permanently open device <--> cloud connection to be able to send/receive messages "in real time". It would not be possible to support more than 12 devices with a single scaling unit if only 12 simultaneous connections were allowed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct in the understanding that the AMQP connection is assumed to remain active in order to achieve "real-time" delivery of cloud-to-device messages.

The throttle you are referring to governs the rate at which new devices can connect to an IoT hub, and not the maximum number of simultaneously connected devices. The throttle is dependent on the number of units that are provisioned for the hub.

For instance, if you buy a single S1 unit, you get a throttle of 100 connections per sec. This means that in order to connect 100.000 devices it would take at least 1000 secs ~ 16mins. You can, however, have as many simultaneously connected devices as you have in your device identity registry.

Usually apps with many devices buy more units, so the throttle increases proportionally (120 connections/sec/unit for S2 units, 12 conn/sec/unit for S1). In case of S1, to accommodate for spikes we never impose a throttle of less than 100 connections/sec, this means that if you buy up to 8 S1 units, you always get 100 connections/sec, when you have 9 you will get 108 connections/sec.

Comment: Sorry Elio ... is it related only to underlying TCP connection ? Can I open AMQP links inside a TCP connection with higher rate then above limits ?

Comment: @Elio thank u so much for ur detailed answer. This is exactly the information I was looking for.